# Is it correct to put "by the way" at the end of sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it correct to put "by the way" at the end of sentence? I don't know it's gramatically correct or not. Sometimes, i use "by the way" at the end of sentence while i'm chatting.

For example,

Do you know? You have to submit this task tomorrow.

And tomorrow there's an exam btw. Don't forget to prepare yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct, you can use "by the way" both at the beginning and at the end of the sentence:

> By the way, there's an exam tomorrow.
>
> There's an exam tomorrow, by the way.

In more formal texts you'd typically separate it with a comma, in chat/text lingo it's often omitted, especially if you're abbreviating:

> ?btw there's an exam tomorrow
>
> ?there's an exam tomorrow btw